# AssemblyInfo file got corrupted VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, assemblies

I have a very bizarre issue,
when I crerate a new project in VS2010, the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file get corrupted:
some line in middle of the file divided to two lines.

why does it's happened?

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("RSAConfiguration")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("
            ")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("RSAConfiguration")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 
             2012")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("4aebd189-5b6f-4f5b-a029-63c6dffe4bfa")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Change your company name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310441) in the registry.